# GLFW3 library in CLion with CMake causes undefined symbols on MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, glfw

I built GLFW from source in MacOS using cmake, and everything went well, the examples are working. But when I was trying to compile a program using cmake in clion, I got the following error:

```
Scanning dependencies of target triangle
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/triangle.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable triangle
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CFArrayAppendValue", referenced from:
    __glfwInitJoysticksNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
    _matchCallback in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFArrayCreateMutable", referenced from:
    __glfwInitJoysticksNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
    _matchCallback in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
... (There are a huge bunch of errors like this, let me know if you want to read all of them)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [triangle] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/triangle.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/triangle.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [triangle] Error 2
```

I browsed through the internet and the documentation and found that I should compile with framework arguments, like this:

```
cc -o myprog myprog.c -lglfw -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit -framework CoreVideo
```

I tried it on the command line, it worked. But what if I want to have things done in CLion(or CMake?) Or how can I use framework in CMake?

My CMakeLists.txt in case you want to know:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(triangle)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(triangle ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(triangle glfw3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added this to my CMakeLists.txt and it works now:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit -framework CoreVideo")
```

so my CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(triangle)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit -framework CoreVideo")
find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(triangle ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(triangle glfw3)
```

I hope there is a more "graceful" way, but this solves my problem now.